# Can we make mouse movements while click an element while video recording in appium python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, appium, appium-android, python-appium

While recording a video can we able to record clicking movement on element? is any option available in appium python?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow :)

you can enable this in "Developer options".
First, to enable "Developer options" (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)

You need to go to "Settings > System > About device > Click 7 times on Build number" after that you will have "Developers options" in "Settings > System".

In "Developer options" you should look for 2 options "Show taps" and "Pointer location", what you are looking for is "Show taps", if you enable this you will see all taps that are happening on the device.

Comment: Hi edvard_munch , I am using Keyboard clicks in unittest python while clickable is not visible

Comment: hey @NirmalJonesStanislaws not sure about keyboard clicks, I haven't found that option in Developer options nor in Keyboard & inputs in settings.I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, you should see where characters are being typed if you send keys to the field.